# How to get a list of folders that I can remove?

Tags: shell, file-permissions, directory

I can get a list of files in my directory:

```
 ls -v
```

But how can I isolate only names of the folders which I have permission to delete?

Comment: Are you asking for the list of folders, or do you really mean the list of folders you have sufficient permissions to delete?  It's certainly possible, but it would get involved to see if you could delete it based on all of user, group, and other.  If that's what you want, I'll come up with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may come as a surprising fact at first, but either all the directories in a specific directory are deletable by you or none are. The key to this is that the permissions that matter when deleting (and creating) directories are the ones for the *parent* directory, and not the directory you're trying to create/delete itself. You may not even be the owner of the directory in question and still be able to delete it:

```
$ mkdir t9
$ chmod a-rxw t9
$ sudo chown root t9
$ ls -ald t9
d--------- 2 root user 4096 Feb 29 12:10 t9
$ rmdir t9 # no error!
```

You can test for write permissions for the current directory with the following shell command:

```
[ -w . ] && echo "writeable parent directory"
```

By the way, to list all directories in the current $PWD this should suffice:

```
ls -al | grep ^d
```

Edit: this may be what you need.

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in `ls -al | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}'`
do
    [ -w $dir ] && echo "user can write in $dir"
done
```

Comment: i create file and can it delete. How can i find: list of directories in which the specified user has the right to delete files?